# Observer pattern using a widget from ipywidgets

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, observer-pattern, ipywidgets

Trying to reproduce the example in http://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_traitlets.html#observe, but using a widget as a class property, the behavior changes and does not observe on changes

```
from ipywidgets import Label
from traitlets import HasTraits, Unicode, observe
class Foo(HasTraits):
    bar = Label()
    baz = Unicode()

    @observe('bar')
    def _observe_bar(self, change):
        print(change['old'])
        print(change['new'])

f = Foo()
f.bar = Label('hello')  # No printing
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer on ipywidgets repo's issue tracker from Sylvain Corlay (https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2078)

> You need to use the `Instance` trait type. (`Instance(Label)`)

So

```
from ipywidgets import Label
from traitlets import HasTraits, Unicode, observe, Instance
class Foo(HasTraits):
    bar = Instance(Label)
    baz = Unicode()

    @observe('bar')
    def _observe_bar(self, change):
        print(change['old'])
        print(change['new'])

f = Foo()
f.bar = Label('hello')  # No printing
```